# Keyboard shorcut for documentation in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Eclipse, if I set the caret above a method and write:

`/**` and click enter, there is an auto documentation of the method with the params that I can easily change.

Is there an equivalent way to do it in xocde?

Comment: You start typing all the strings and select those lines and press cmd+/

Comment: what do you mean by start typing all the strings?

Comment: in .h or .m if you want to add any documentation, simply type them. once you are done. select all the lines and press cmd+/

Comment: I am afraid that you misunderstood me. I wouldn't want to add comment myself, but have an auto tool like in Eclipse. If you were an Eclipse user in the past you would understand my question

Comment: I understood, that is why i didnt post it as answer, In the mean time i was searching for any scipts available in xcode4, in xcode3 it was there for few things...

Comment: Not an Eclipse-user so not sure if I get you right, but if you hold down the alt-key and hover over any class-name in your code you'll get a brief description as well as a link to the complete class reference...

Comment: I don't need the documentation - I would like to add a new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut for that.

However you can create your own shortcut by using [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html).

Put documentation and comment them by selecting them and pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

You can find more info here : [How to add custom keyboard shortcut to xcode targeting a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400756/xcode-4-custom-behavior-does-not-execute-my-sh-script).

And for better documentation tool [HeadDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html) and [AutoGSDoc](http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Tools/Reference/autogsdoc.html).

Comment: @Odelya : check my answer, i have updated a link where you can find similar thing

Comment: It's not the script that I am looking for. I am not looking to generate external HTML, but an internal documentation for other developers like in Eclipse

Comment: @Odelya : it is not the exact solution for you. But this shows how you can do something automated. Also you need to use keyboard-Shortcut for  putting /** */. It may not come automatically as in other IDEs...